# Smtp DSN Test symfony mailcatcher in local : Nothing received

Tags: symfony

I setup a testing SMTP inbox with mailtrap.io

[image]

I've then added this DSN configuration to my env.

Then I'm trying to test the mail sending process.

```
public function sendEmailConfirmation(string $verifyEmailRouteName, UserInterface $user, TemplatedEmail $email): void
{
    $signatureComponents = $this->verifyEmailHelper->generateSignature(
        $verifyEmailRouteName,
        $user->getId(),
        $user->getEmail()
    );

    $context = $email->getContext();
    $context['signedUrl'] = $signatureComponents->getSignedUrl();
    $context['expiresAtMessageKey'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageKey();
    $context['expiresAtMessageData'] = $signatureComponents->getExpirationMessageData();

    $email->context($context);
    //dump($email);
    //dd("Send mail");
    $this->mailer->send($email);
}
```

As you can see, I'm properly reaching the send method

[image]

But even with that, I'm still getting nothing in the mailtrap inbox.

Am I missing something there ?

EDIT : The test were made without the dump and die so yes the execution reach te send method. I'm even redirected to an other page later without any specific error 500 proving that there is nothing going wrong with the code. The issue being I really didn't receive the email.

EDIT 2 : THis is what I have in database from my tests

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279544/when-i-try-to-send-an-email-it-is-not-sent-but-stored-in-the-messenger-message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546892/symfony-6-cant-send-email-with-mailer-without-configured-database

Comment: auto flagging the question, @yivi first link solved the issue. Thanks. Thought I haven't been able to find any documentation about that configuration.

Answer (score -1):

your execution will never send the mail, since you let the application die before it.

```
dd("Send mail")
$this->mailer->send($email);
```

You dump-and-die with the message "Send mail" and the `$this->mailer->send($email)` is never executed. That's where the email is sent.

Comment: I obviously just added the die to show the dump example^^but sorry it might not have been obvious

Comment: It still dies before the mail is being send in your code example.  What happens if you remove that line? Will it throw any exception, have you tried the debugging emails section? https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#debugging-emails

Comment: I updated the code as my english might be bad sorry. But thats what i'm saying since the start, I've added the dump die only because it wasn't sending mail, for testing purpose. There is no dump die in my code it was just to prove that the code was reaching the send instruction. There is no error thrown by the code when it's being executed even without the dump die.

Comment: This is unrelated to the issue at hand. And if it **was** really related, then one should be flagging to close the question as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". In this case, it seems more likely that the question should have been closed as a duplicate.